# Why is FindNextFile failing on Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi

This code works on Windows XP at home but fails at work on 64bit Windows 7. The loop isn't entered even once although there are more than 50 files in the supplied folder. Not only it doesn't enter, it also returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` for `GetLastError`. Why?

```
string dir = "d:\\validfolder";
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(dir.c_str(), &ffd);
while(FindNextFile(h, &ffd))
{
// some operation
}
DWORD dw = GetLastError();// returns ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES
```

I tried `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` but that has no effect.

Comment: Why do you have three \ in your dir name?

Comment: Ah, the preview was showing single slash when I added double so I compensated for it. I guess I hadn't formatted it properly. There's only two slashes in the actual code.

Comment: It is pretty unclear why you are throwing away the first result, the one returned by FindFirstFile.  The error code is otherwise entirely normal, that's how you know there are no more files and you've seen them all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a file wildcard to your dir:

```
string dir = "d:\\validfolder\\*";
```

For it to list the files in a directory.  Otherwise you are only asking for information about the directory itself.

At least that's how I read the documentation for [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> To examine a directory that is not a root directory, use the path to
>   that directory, without a trailing backslash. For example, an argument
>   of "C:\Windows" returns information about the directory "C:\Windows",
>   not about a directory or file in "C:\Windows". To examine the files
>   and directories in "C:\Windows", use an lpFileName of "C:\Windows*".

I don't know why it's working for you on XP

Comment: That's odd TBH. I am pretty sure I hadn't used the wild card on XP. I'll have to check again. Anyway this works . Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This code is incorrect in a number of ways.

You must check the return value of `FindFirstFile`. If the call to `FindFirstFile` succeeds then you already have the first file in `ffd`. As your code stands, you throw away the first file. So you need to re-jig your loop logic to account for that. Naturally, if `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` then that means the search has exhausted all files.

So, what is probably happening is you ask for the first file matching the search string `"d:\\validfolder"`. This is returned in `ffd` after the call to `FindFirstFile`. You then ignore that information and ask for the next match. But there is no subsequent match since there is only one object matching `"d:\\validfolder"` since you included no wildcards in your search pattern.

This code will behave exactly the same on XP as it does on Windows 7 and I suspect that you are not running the same code on both systems.

If you want to enumerate the contents of the folder then you need to search for `"d:\\validfolder\\*"`. Something like this:

```
string dir = "d:\\validfolder\\*";
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(dir.c_str(), &ffd);
BOOL success = h<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
while(success)
{
    // do something with ffd
    success = FindNextFile(h, &ffd));
}
```

Comment: It was about not having used the wild card. As far as the code goes, I just cropped it and pasted the absolute relevant portions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you write the loop as per the code in the question then you will miss the first hit. You should write the loop the way I do above. Or do you mean that your real code is different from the code in the question. We can only comment on the code in the question.